# What is the best approach to use Vaadin for web application development?

Tags: java, web-services, vaadin

I am just about to create a new Web application (kind of CRM system) with lot of tables, statistics, graphs, etc... and I've decided to do the web interface with Vaadin. Most of the data will come from external Web Services (almost 100 %). My Question is, what would be the best approach to go with? Just to implement pure Vaadin application and some classes to handle the SOAP calls and fill the Vaadin components with the data, or to go with some additional framework e.g. Spring, Struts, etc... and integrate vaading for the UI? Any additional hints would be great.

Thanks
Filip

Answer (score 2):

Using spring is good for dependency injection, security (depending on the sections you are using) but struts and vaadin are web frameworks so mixing them does no sense. You either use struts or vaadin or spring-mvc or any other web framework.

Your question is not really clear but I would say you can use spring rest api to pull data from other web services if they are restful services.

Comment: As far as I know, Vaading is a WebUI framework, so I would still need some classes to perform the business logic (Vaading only displays the data on the frontend). Observer pattern is used in the Vaadin, so all components are updated upon events like mouseclicks, etc.. from the web layer. Vaadin must than get the data from somewhere. My question is if it makes any sense (or is reasonable) to implement this "something" with any existing framework(spring?) and use Vaadin as the presentation logic. Or is it better to go with some custom solution using existing tools for SOAP calls, Security stuff.

Comment: business layer is business layer so you don't really need a framework to implement that bit. However, spring will ease some of the common stuff as i would say yes, vaadin+spring would do what want to do.